# Hover menu animated

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to make a jquery menu looking like the one in this website.
I'm searching all around the net but actually, I cannot find the correct searching name to google it.

here is the example:

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39116.html

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The example site you posted is using the Superfish Plugin for jQuery - you can [get the plugin here](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started)

> Superfish is an enhanced Suckerfish-style menu jQuery plugin that takes an existing pure CSS drop-down menu (so it degrades gracefully without JavaScript) and adds the following much-sought-after enhancements:

Comment: I'm sorry, It think I did not explained correctly what I was looking for. Actually, I'm looking for a the background effect in the menu I showed.